# ajax request jqmobi

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, jqmobi

I'm using the jqMobi framework for a web application. In my app, I insert an anchor on my page and attach a ajax call. When I click it does the ajax call but returns no content.  If i directly access the URL in my browser I see the correct result.

I get the following error in console:

> Error loading content with Target: url972955173 was not found # - #
>   url972955173

Any idea what the cause might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed in the 0.9.3 release. If you go to http://www.github.com/appmobi/jq.mobi and click "zip", it will download the code in the repository (0.9.3 isn't uploaded yet).